# ggplot: assign manual break points to date scale

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2, scale

I have some time series data and I would like to customize the x-axis (dates) to show the date labels where I obtain measurements, as opposed to having regular breaks per week/month/year.

Sample data:

```
dates <- as.Date("2011/01/01") + sample(0:365, 5, replace=F)
number <- sample(1:100, 5)

    df <- data.frame(
      dates = dates,
      number = number
    )
```

This way I can plot my df with regular breaks every month...

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(dates), number)) + 
  geom_point(size=6) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = dates, y = 0, xend = dates, yend = number),
               size=0.5, linetype=2) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%d-%b-%Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5))
```

... but I would like to set the major breaks to the actual 5 dates in `df$dates`. It works with a normal continuous scale (`scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 3, 7, 9))`) but I can't figure out how to do it for a continuous date scale.

I am looking to do something like...

```
scale_dates_continuous(breaks = df$dates)
```

...but that doesn't exist unfortunately. Thanks lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read `?scale_x_date`, about the `breaks` argument: you can use a "vector of breaks". Thus, try

```
scale_x_date(breaks = df$dates, labels = date_format("%d-%b-%Y"))
```